Can you display search result in the same order in Intellij Find in Files
I have unchecked "show recent files at the top of results list" in the settings. But still, each time when searching for a string, the result list is displayed in different orders. Is it possible to keep the result list in the same order or even alphabetically. Thanks

If you want to sort the search results in the alphabetical order of the file name, then you can try the following procedure

Go to 'Edit' -> 'Find' -> 'Find in Files...' or use the keyboard shortcut 'Ctrl+Shift+F' to search string and perform the search operation
Click on 'Open in Find Window' button at the bottom right corner of the popup
The results will be displayed in a bottom pane. Here, you need to click on the Group by icon and uncheck all the options as shown in below image.

Later click on the gear icon at the top right corner of the pane and Go to 'View Options' -> Check 'Sort Members Alphabetically' as shown in below image

Now you can see the results in the alphabetical order of the file names.

P.S: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.7 (Community Edition)
